# View Permissions generated for Android on CodenameOne

Tags: codenameone

Problem is Google Play removes my application for not sticking to their requirements. In code nameone there is no way of checking which of the permissions are we missing. I want to know if there is a way to know which permissions are being used. Just like android studio manifest file i can see which permissions have been included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unzip the APK and look at the manifest file or use any 3rd party APK inspection tool. You can use include source and look at the manifest file directly or open it in Android Studio.